# What Stackdriver monitoring filters shall I use to select a pcollection of a dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Stackdriver Monitoring Dashboard to monitor the "element_count" of a "pcollection" in a "dataflow_job" with "job_name=xxxx".

[Fliters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOv8e.png)

Below is the filter string which I learned from this link.
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#time-series-filter
I need this string for other purposes.

'resource.type = "dataflow_job" AND metric.type = "dataflow.googleapis.com/job/element_count" AND resource.labels.job_name = "MY_DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME"'

However, with this filter string, I am selecting all the pcollections.

My question is, to select one pcollection, what filter should I add to the filter string? I suppose it is something like

'AND **resource.labels.pcollection** = "PubsubIO.Read/MapElements/Map.out0"'

But **resource.lables.pcollection** seems not working for me. I searched online but didn't find any answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "job/element_count" metric is documented on
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-dataflow as having a **metric** label for pcollection, so you'd want to use **metric.labels.pcollection**, i.e.

`AND metric.labels.pcollection = "PubsubIO.Read/MapElements/Map.out0"`

The resource labels are documented at 
[https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_dataflow_job),
and `dataflow_job` resource type does not have a "pcollection" label.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes it should be metric.labels.pcollection. To find the filters in JSON format, simply go to monitoring overview > metric explorer, select the filters you like, and click on the three dots on the upper right corner of the chart, you can see "View as JSON". Then you can get the filter you need.

Comment: Two more comments: 1. The "View as JSON" is only visible in Metric Explorer, which is not very obvious to everyone. Maybe this can be added to anytime you create a chart. 2. I have read the above first link. However, I cannot figure out the format is metric.labels.pcollection. Personally I think it is not user friendly. Hope this help the development team.